# how md5 byte array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, node.js

in NodeJS:

```
>var md5 = require('md5')
>md5([1])
55a54008ad1ba589aa210d2629c1df41
```

in Ruby:

```
pry(main)> Digest::MD5.hexdigest [1]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
from (pry):20:in `digest'
```

I am trying to use 'Array#pack' to convert a byte array to big-endian 32-bit words in:

```
pry(main)> Digest::MD5.hexdigest [1].pack('L*')
=> "4352d88a78aa39750bf70cd6f27bcaa5"
```

But result is different with nodejs, I am not familiar with byte operation, Please let me know how to use ruby to get same result with nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ▶ Digest::MD5.hexdigest [1].pack 'U*'
 #⇒ "55a54008ad1ba589aa210d2629c1df41"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but result different when array contain multiple elements, like `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Different means what? Your question is not marked with [tag:node] and I have no idea how this piece of code treats md5-ing arrays of integers. **Anyway, corrected my answer, please check.**

Comment: thank you, `[1].pack 'U+'` is right, but `[1].pack 'U+'` and `[1,2,3].pack 'U+'` are same result, the result should be different when byte array different